# Проблема с координатами

Tags: c#, графика, java

Задаю координаты круга и задаю ему радиус 100. Потом создаю аналогичный второй круг. Когда они приближаются друг к другу и сталкиваются, то растояние между центрами масс кругов должно быть меньше или равно суме радиусов. Но на самом деле срабатывает event, что **`sumOfRadiuses > distanceBetweenCenterOfMass`**, но на самом деле на картинке явно видно, что они далеко друг от друга.

Я подозреваю, что проблема в радиусе.
Вот, например, java doc:

```
public abstract void fillOval(int x, int y, int width, int height)

width - the width of the oval to be filled.
height - the height of the oval to be filled.
```

Как оно потом интерпретирует эту ширину ? И как тогда преобразовать тогда, чтобы вычисления были точными?

Comment: > Как оно потом интерпретирует эту ширину ?

На сколько я понимаю, это ширина и высота, т.е. есть некий прямоугольник, заданный данными параметрами, в который вписывается овал. x, y - левый верхний, width, height - размер.

Comment: Теперь понятно. А то я предполагал, что это радиусы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробую предположить, что `width`/`height` — это диаметр (а вы считаете его радиусом). Соответственно `(x, y)` — координаты левого верхнего угла.

Таким образом, имеем такой код:

```
class Circle
{
    double centerX;
    double centerY;
    double radius;

    public virtual void draw(Graphics graphics)
    {
        int topleftX = (int)Math.round(centerX - radius);
        int topleftY = (int)Math.round(centerY - radius);

        int bottomrightX = (int)Math.round(centerX + radius);
        int bottomrightY = (int)Math.round(centerY + radius);

        int width = bottomrightX - topleftX;
        int height = bottomrightY - topleftY;

        graphics.fillOval(topleftX, topleftY, width, height);
    }

    boolean hasCollision(Circle other)
    {
        double dx = centerX - other.centerX;
        double dy = centerY - other.centerY;
        double distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return distance <= radius + other.radius;
    }
}
```

По идее должно работать.

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Comment: @nullptr: пожалуйста!